# Python SocketServer.TCPServer request

Tags: python, socketserver

I've been playing around with Python's SocketServer:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import SocketServer

class EchoHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data=self.request.recv(1024)
        self.request.send(data)

HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), TCPEchoServer)
server.serve_forever()
```

From reading the source, I know that `RequestHandler.__init__()` receives `request` as a parameter and keeps a reference to it in `self.request`.

Where can I find the specifications for the `request` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [documentation of `RequestHandler.handle`](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.RequestHandler.handle).

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I missed it.